# Получение данных из БД , Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java

Добрый день!
У меня есть некоторая БД и сущности, с которыми я работаю в сервлете.

вот отрывок кода из *doGet, doPost*. Оговорюсь сразу, что внутри все мои *DAO* объекты выглядят примерно так:

```
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        launches = session.createCriteria(LaunchesEntity.class).list();
        tx.commit();            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        launches = session.createCriteria(LaunchesEntity.class).list();
        tx.commit();
```

Ну а теперь код из *doGet, doPost* :

```
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    //достаем из базы ВСЕ тесты
    Iterable<TestsEntity> alltest = Factory.getInstance().getTestsDAO().getAllTests();

    for (TestsEntity testsEntity : alltest) {

        Transaction tx2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .beginTransaction();
        Iterable<ResultEntity> results = testsEntity.getResultsByTestId();

        for (ResultEntity result : results) {
            //получаем  Запуск с данным результатом
            LaunchesEntity launch = result.getLaunchesByLaunchId();
            //получим все Параметры Запуска
            Iterable<ParamsAndValuesEntity> allParamsAndValues = launch
                    .getParamsAndValuesesByLaunchId();
            String paramsInString = null;
            for (ParamsAndValuesEntity paramAndValue : allParamsAndValues) {
                paramsInString+= " [" + paramAndValue.getParamsByParamsId().getParamName() +
                        "= " + paramAndValue.getParamValue() + "] ";
            }

            Map row= new HashMap();
            row.put("test_name", testsEntity.getName());
             .........
            //row.put("request_text", launch.getRequestText());
            aaData.add(row);
        }

        tx2.commit();

    }

  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
```

Диаграмму БД, могу при желании прислать. Но скажу сразу, там есть разные связи : один-ко-многим, многие-ко-многим.

При деплое Томката, получаю exception:

```
  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DataTableBackend] in context with path [/TestManager] threw exception
  org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:       models.TestsEntity.resultsByTestId, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
at    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
at DataTableBackend.doGet(DataTableBackend.java:75)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

PS подскажите люди добрые как решить проблему, может подскажите работающее решение по вытаскиванию данных из БД. Оговрюсь сразу, что данные, как вы видите, представляю сложные запросы в связанные таблицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так как описано в решении аналогичной проблемы [Hibernate could not initialize proxy - no Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492410/hibernate-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session)

Comment: не, тут ситуация куда сложнее

Comment: я смотрю на ваш код и откровенно говоря испытываю тихи ужос. это у вас продакшин система или пока только тренируетесь? 

Если это у вас тестовый проект то для того чтобы понять в чем там дело вы бы выложили его на github или bitbucket так будет лучше для понимания.

Comment: это тестовый проект) я пока только учусь работать с hibernate , да и со всем *JAVA EE* . Все заработало! Надо было почистить код, и согласовать его с простыми правилами: верное открытие сессии, комит транзакции.